# "Join" two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, lookup, reduce

Whats the most efficient way to join two arrays in Google Apps Script?

I have one two dimensional array that is ordered by the id:

```
[
[1, "A", "B", "C"],
[2, "B", "B", "B"],
[3, "C", "A", "B"],
]
```

and another array like

```
[
[1, "D"],
[3, "B"],
[2, "B"],
]
```

What is the most efficient way to end up with:

```
[
[1, "A", "B", "C", "D"],
[2, "B", "B", "B", "B"],
[3, "C", "A", "B", "B"],
]
```

Comment: Second array is confusing. The result will be the same, even if the first element in the inner array is 1,2,3 instead of 1,3,2. Also, Is  the first element unique? What if there's 1,3,3 ?

Comment: First element is unique.

Comment: Convert the second array to a object with your unique keys. Then you can call them easily using the key and push it to the end of array.

Comment: Please add a brief description of you search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: @J. G. Can I ask you about your question? When `[3, "B"]` and `[2, "B"]` of `[[1, "D"],[3, "B"],[2, "B"]]` are `[3, "B3"]` and `[2, "B2"]`, respectively, what result do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function combine() {
  var vA=[[1, "A", "B", "C"],[2, "B", "B", "B"],[3, "C", "A", "B"]];
  var vB=[[1, "D"],[3, "B"],[2, "B"]];        
  for(var i=0;i<vB.length;i++) {
    vA[i].splice(vA[i].length,0,vB[i][1]);
  }
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vA));
}
```

Comment: The result only appears correct due to `[3, "B"]` and `[2, "B"]` both featuring `"B"` as 2nd entry. The provided solution does not take into account the slightly off order of `[[1, "D"],[3, "B"],[2, "B"]]` where the 2nd item is `[3, "B"]` instead of `[2, "B"]`.  In case of `[[1, "D"],[3, "Y"],[2, "X"]]` the result would log `[[1,"A","B","C","D"],[2,"B","B","B","Y"],[3,"C","A","B","X"]]` instead of the correct `[[1,"A","B","C","D"],[2,"B","B","B","X"],[3,"C","A","B","Y"]]`.

Answer (score 0):

A feasible efficient and generic approach which does not mutate any of the originally provided data structures could be built upon an intermediate lookup table (called `targetIndex`) which gets created via [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) from the provided source data.

The creation of such an intermediate index via additionally utilizing [`structuredClone`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/structuredClone) not only brings the advantage of a fast to be looked up object-based structure for the later merge/concat task, but as for the deep cloning of the sub-arrays, it also prevents the source data from getting modified/mutated.

The custom merge/concat task then happens via iterating the to be merged data array ([`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) based) and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)ing the additional data into the related sub-array of the intermediate index, with the final result then just being the pure [`values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)-array representation of said intermediate index.

The approach enables implementations which out of the box do handle further changes to the to be merged array data as long as the first item of each sub-array can be used as identifier for sub-arrays of the provided source data.

```js
const sourceData = [
  [1, "A", "B", "C"],
  [2, "B", "B", "B"],
  [3, "C", "A", "B"],
];
const mergeTable = [
  [1, "D"],
  [3, "D"],
  [2, "B"],
];

// - creation of an intermediate index (lookup table)  
//   with already deeply cloned `sourceData` sub-arrays.
// - deep cloning via `structuredClone` allows `sourceData`
//   to remain entirely unmodified / non-mutated.
const targetIndex = sourceData
  .reduce((index, sourceDataItem) => {

    const markerKey = sourceDataItem[0];
    index[markerKey] = structuredClone(sourceDataItem);

    return index;
  }, {});

// - `mergeTable` is the only source of truth
//   for the OP's custom merge/concat task.
// - thus, the intermediate `targetIndex` will
//   be updated from the former also by taking
//   advantage of easily looking up the latter.
mergeTable
  .forEach(([markerKey, ...mergeData]) => {

    targetIndex[markerKey].push(...mergeData)
  });

// - the final result is just the pure `values`-array
//   representation of the intermediate `targetIndex`.
const targetData = Object
  .values(targetIndex);

// - none of the originlly provided data has been mutated.
console.log({ sourceData, mergeTable, targetData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

A mutating solution might be faster for it does not use `structuredClone` and also skips the final `Object.values` operation.

```js
const tableData = [
  [1, "A", "B", "C"],
  [2, "B", "B", "B"],
  [3, "C", "A", "B"],
];
const mergeTable = [
  [1, "X1", "X2"],
  [3, "Z1", "Z2"],
  [2, "Y1", "Y2"],
];

const updateIndex = tableData
  .reduce((index, tableDataItem) => {

    const markerKey = tableDataItem[0];
    index[markerKey] = tableDataItem;

    return index;
  }, {});

mergeTable
  .forEach(([markerKey, ...mergeData]) => {

    updateIndex[markerKey].push(...mergeData)
  });

// - already mutated / merged `tableData`.
console.log({ tableData });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```